# Can MySql rollback a sql transaction over multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have searched the MySql documentation and found nothing. I have tried this ... the Rollback doesn't seem to cancel the inserts made in table1 and table2

```
Start Transaction;

INSERT INTO Table1(field1,field2) VALUES (value1, value2);

INSERT INTO Table2(field3,field4) VALUES (value3, value4);

INSERT INTO Table3(field5,field6) VALUES (value5, value6);

Rollback;
```

**UPDATE**: Thanks for all answers, but I forgot to tell that the 3rd statement **throws an exception** (Constraint Violation).

Comment: Are you using a transactional engine for all these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of current version of MySql v5.1 ... it does not support rollback over multiple tables ... That might change (I hope) in the near future!

Answer (score 10):

Yes, but only for tables that support transactions.  To check if your tables are compatible, do this

```
SELECT table_name
     , engine
  FROM information_schema.tables t
 WHERE t.table_name IN('Table1','Table2','Table3');
```

If any of them are `MyISAM`, they are not transaction compatible.  You'll need to change them all to `InnoDB`

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

But be warned - MyISAM supports some features that InnoDB does not, such as FULLTEXT searches.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the beginning of your script:

```
SET autocommit=0;
```

By default, MySQL will issue a commit after each statement, unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: I tried this ... it doesn't work if an error was thrown in the middle of the script.

Comment: Not a good idea, because if you mistakenly delete records - you won't be able to roll the transaction back.

Comment: start transaction set automatically autocommit off.