# How to rollback changes made to a database with presence of Try Catch Statement in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, try-catch

I use try catch statements in almost every one of my insert or update statements on a site built with PHP and MySQL. In the event of something like:

```
try {
    //do insert or update
}

catch (PDOException $e) {
   $db->rollback();
   //do something with error $e
}
```

in this example, if an error occurs, anything that was done to the DB will be rolled back (changes reversed) and all is "well". I am not certain however how to handle situations in which multiple insert or update statements exist in one try/catch - how even multiple try/catches on one page.

Ultimately I am trying to solve: if an error is found in a script which does not allow a single insert/update (try/catch) statement to complete, to rollback the changes made to ALL tables within that particular script.

Is there a reliable way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to only have **one** action in each transaction. you can have multiple.

For example:

When you go to the bank's atm: do you log in, get cash. log out. log back in. make a deposit. log out. (and on..)
**OR** Do you Log in. Get cash, make deposit. (and on...) log out. ?

Comment: I already wrap multiple statements in a single try/catch (if that is what you are implying) but if an error occurs, the rollback only occurs on the table affected by the error.

Comment: @JM4 -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094398/can-mysql-rollback-a-sql-transaction-over-multiple-tables

Comment: issue found, thanks for the link. All of my tables are MyISAM

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to rollback changes is to make sure of three major things:

- Use `START TRANSACTION/COMMIT` or `START TRANSACTION/ROLLBACK`
- All tables used in the Transaction use the InnoDB Storage Engine
- Use CHECKPOINTs in the event you want to rollback some INSERTs/UPDATEs and not all

## CAVEAT

Please make sure you do not issue any of the following commands in the middle of a transaction because they launch an implicit COMMIT and begin a new transaction:

- `ALTER TABLE`
- `BEGIN`
- `CREATE INDEX`
- `DROP DATABASE`
- `DROP INDEX`
- `DROP TABLE`
- `RENAME TABLE`
- `TRUNCATE TABLE`
- `LOCK TABLES`
- `UNLOCK TABLES`
- `SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1`
- `START TRANSACTION`

Answer (score 1):

The "easy" way would be to use [ADOdb for PHP](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) with InnoDB tables and the "mysqlt" database type.  The DBAL takes care of keeping track of all the changes made during a transaction and will roll them back for you if asked.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. My Tables are in myisam format currently and I actually jsut spent quite a bit of time converting all of our code using PDO so not looking to switch again unless the benefits of such a switch are well worth the effort.

Comment: I would think that transactions shouldn't work (i.e. your call to $db->rollback() doesn't actually do anything) as MyISAM doesn't support transactions.

Comment: yep, see my comment above. Thanks for suggestion about ADOdb - i'll have to check it out.

Comment: Right on, glad to help.  Just keep in mind that for ADOdb to do transactions, the underlying tables have to support it also (it doesn't do artificial transactions).